# Использование `NullReferenceException`

Tags: c#, исключения, .net-core, расширения

Да, я знаю что `NullReferenceException` — это системная ошибка (наследование от `SystemException` + применение), но что мне выбрасывать вот в таком коде:

```cs
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void Import(IModuleSource module);
}
```

```cs
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void ImportKernel(this IMyInterface @this)
    {
        @this.Import(new KernelSource(KernelVersion.Latest)); // импортируем ядро
    }
}
```

<sup>**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.** Псевдо-код. Фокус должен быть не на методах `Import` и `ImportKernel`, а на "прологе" метода `ImportKernel`.</sup>

Тут есть 1 проблема — параметр `@this` в методе `ImportKernel` может быть `null`. Следовательно, этот вход нужно обработать. И тут возникает 2 способа решения:

```cs
if (@this is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(@this));
```

```cs
if (@this is null) throw new NullReferenceException();
```

Кажется, что 2-й способ неконкурентоспособен, но метод `ImportKernel` можно вызвать также по разному:

```cs
IMyInterface obj = null!;

// исключение `ArgumentNullException` не уместно, т.к. мы не передаём аргумент `this`
// исключение `NullReferenceException` выглядит естественно
obj.ImportKernel();
```

```cs
// исключение `ArgumentNullException` выглядит естественно
// исключение `NullReferenceException` выглядит не уместно, т.к. класс `MyExtensions` не может быть `null` (да он, собственно, и не объект)
MyExtensions.ImportKernel(null!);
```

И не понятно, что делать?

Конечно, можно создать своё исключение — `ObjectNullException`, но оно не входит в стандартную библиотеку, значит у каждого будет по такому исключению, что не хорошо.

Собственно, вопрос: какое исключение лучше выбрасывать в данной ситуации (или не выбрасывать ничего <s>на крайняк</s>)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788218/c-best-practice-for-validating-this-argument-in-extension-methods

Comment: @ExplodingKitten мне не очень нравиться вариант с `ArgumentNullException`, т.к. в 99% случаев вы будете получать сообщение о том, что какой-то аргумент `null`, хотя аргумента с таким именем вы не передавали. +там нет варианта "своё исключение"

Comment: я добавил эту ссылку не как ответ, а мнение от одного из разработчиков c#, т.к. ваши вопросы похожи

Comment: Всё равно бросайте `ArgumentNullException`. Потому что для _статического_ метода `ImportKernel` `@this` является именно _аргументом_ и не важно, что он используется как метод расширения. / Попробуйте linq-методы вызвать на какой-либо коллекции, равной `null` - убедитесь сами в получаемом исключении.

Comment: Все же просто, если метод не инвокается, потому что объект-владелец метода отсутствует, то есть `null`, рантайм бросит `NullReferenceException`, и дело до проверки внутри метода не дойдет. Если же дело дошло до провереи аргумента, и он `null`, то бросается `ArgumentNullException`. Исключение говорит само за себя. Здесь логика настолько прозрачна, что я даже понять не могу, почему этот момент оказался для вас спорным. Ну и как выше подсказали, можно поиграться с `Linq` как с образцом, где мелкомягкие уже решили этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант собственно очевидный для меня. Для кого другой пишите свой ответ.

Вариант. `if (@this is null) throw new NullReferenceException();`  Не имеет смысла поскольку следующая команда сделает это за вас.

Писать своё исключение это хорошая практика. (не утверждаю о правильности, правильно и хорошо не инвариант. Всё индивидуально).

Comment: вариант "не писать" ухудшает читаемость + когда я вижу необработанный аргумент у меня сразу руки тянуться написать его обработку через `if`'ы

Comment: так своё исключение писать или нет, в каких ситуациях да, а в каких нет?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал лучше так

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool IsImportKernelSuccess(this IMyInterface @this)
    {
        if (@this is null)
            return false;

         @this.Import(new KernelSource(KernelVersion.Latest));
         return true;
    }
}
```

Или можно еще попытаться избежать на входе в метод `null` с помощью паттерна `NullObject`.

Comment: во-первых, лучше `TryImportKernel`. во-вторых, мне теперь все методы расширений для классов делать как `TryXXX`? это неудобно, хоть убейте.

Comment: тут речь идёт не о возврате `bool`'а, а от том, какое исключение выбросить. и причём тут fluent interface? просто если ты возвращаешь `bool`, который отвечает на вопрос "всё ли нормально?", то я его называю TryXXX, т.к. почти всегда есть его версия, возвращающая результат (например, `TryParse` и `Parse`)

Comment: Да, с названием вы правы. ` во-вторых, мне теперь все методы расширений для классов делать как TryXXX?` в таком случае применяйте паттерн `NullObject`.

Comment: про null object я прекрасно знаю и постоянно его использую, но только там, где это уместно. в моём случае мне категорически нужно получить объект `@this`. да, конечно, моно просто выйти из метода. но это не в стиле C# — тут только исключение. И создание `struct`-wrapper'а тут тоже не поможет, т.к. null-поведение у этого объекта — выброс исключения.